# How to sort unique values based on another column in R

Tags: r

I would like to extract unique values based on the sum in another column. For example, I have the following data frame `"music"`

```
ID    | Song            |  artist       | revenue 
7520  | Dance with me   |   R kelly     |   2000    
7531  | Gone girl       |   Vincent     |   1890     
8193  | Motivation      |   R Kelly     |   3500     
9800  | What            |   Beyonce     |  12000    
2010  | Excuse Me       |   Pharell     |   1010     
1999  | Remove me       |   Jack Will   |    500
```

Basically, I would like to sort the top 5 artists based on revenue, without the duplicate entries on a given artist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the `dplyr` way:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
ID    | Song            |  artist       | revenue 
7520  | Dance with me   |   R Kelly     |   2000    
7531  | Gone girl       |   Vincent     |   1890     
8193  | Motivation      |   R Kelly     |   3500     
9800  | What            |   Beyonce     |  12000    
2010  | Excuse Me       |   Pharell     |   1010     
1999  | Remove me       |   Jack Will   |    500      
", header = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)
```

You can `group_by` the artist, and then you can choose how many entries you want to peak at (here just 3):

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(artist) %>%
  summarise(tot = sum(revenue)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(tot)) %>%
  head(3)
```

Result:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

   artist   tot
1 Beyonce 12000
2 R Kelly  5500
3 Vincent  1890
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need `order()` to do this. For instance:

```
head(unique(music$artist[order(music$revenue, decreasing=TRUE)]))
```

or, to retain all columns (although uniqueness of artists would be a little trickier):

```
head(music[order(music$revenue, decreasing=TRUE),])
```